# How to simulate 2d 3D-like (lay down)

Tags: windows-phone-7, 3d, xna, 2d

If I have a grid of text and image, like calendar view. If I want the entire grid to lay down 45 degree and still be able to respond to finger click/scroll, how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you're doing this in XNA, you're going to want to use Billboarding. I'm afraid I haven't had a need for billboarding yet, so I can't give you specifics, but as usual there's a [Riemers Tutorial](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Billboarding.php) for that. Now, specifically you want to have an interactive billboard with controls. This will be complicated if you've never had 3D experience before. Here's what you will want to do:

1. Draw your controls/text as you normally would with SpriteBatch, but set the RenderTarget of the GraphicsDevice to a new RenderTarget beforehand, which you save. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198872%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) for documentation on changing the rendertarget. Remember to set it back after you've drawn your controls.
2. Now convert the RenderTarget to a Texture2D using explicit casting: `Texture2D myTex = (Texture2D)myRenderTarget;`
3. Draw this texture on the billboard.
4. Now comes the tricky part: you need to use a technique called "Picking" to determine where in 3D space the user has clicked. App Hub has some picking tutorials, but they're geared toward complex models. Since billboarding only uses a plane with 2 triangles, they won't work with any accuracy in this case, which you need. Instead, I recommend [using Viewport.UnProject to pick on the plane](http://www.enchantedage.com/xna-picking).

Essentially, you're going to want to have a good system to keep track of where the clickable things are on your billboard in 3D space. You can use plane equations for this, if you know them (I think I learned those in Calculus III). If you only need basic functionality you can use these equations to only keep track of the center of your buttons, then do a radius test for clicking, though this isn't entirely accurate unless your buttons are circles.

If you can't tell, things get complicated fast when you try to apply 2D concepts in a 3D world.

Answer (score 4):

There's a really simple solution to this.
If you open up the project using Expression Blend, once you have selected the grid, go to the property tab, scrow down to 'Transform', there should be a property called 'Rotation', just change the X: Y: Z: values until the grid is rotated to the way you want it to look. It acts exactly as you'd expect it to.

Here's the XAML code:

```
<Grid.Projection>
    <PlaneProjection RotationX="-43"/>
</Grid.Projection>
```

Comment: I thought I wrote "XNA" at subject but it is somehow gone. I was struggled to use either XNA or silverlight. But I feel more comfortable using XNA because it is straight-forward. Can Silverlight adds control inside the grid dynamically? Draw text and image inside the control of grid? Can the rotaion change dynamically? Can handle click event with newly added control inside the grid? Please advise! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure about creating controls because I haven't done that myself, but yes to draw text and image, yes to changing rotation dynamically, not sure about handling events for newly created control. Have you tried the MSDN article on Silverlight controls?